# Why isn't the batman question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was just curious to know, why [the Batman question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real) is not closed? As far I know, it provides no insight and no proof that the person did research before they posted the question. Are we just keeping it around because it has so many upvotes and a really good answer? Could something be done about this?

EDIT:

It is true that I would like to see the question closed and I have presented my opinion on the issue but I am not strongly suggesting that the question be closed. I am curious to know why this question isn't closed more than I want the question to be closed. Asking to close the question is only the consequence of the fact that I do (did) not understand why such as question was not closed. I have read the comments below and I'm getting some picture of why the question hasn't been closed.

Comment: In the title you ask why it's not closed, but then write "are we just keeping it around..." Note that closed questions are kept around just as the rest of them. It's just that new answers cannot be added. As far as I'm concerned, the question can be closed or left open, I'm not going to vote either way. But I would certainly oppose its deletion, because it has good answers that should be kept.

Comment: @5pm I'm only curious as to why this question isn't close. I would not want the question to be closed at all! Because the answers that have been provided are in-depth and explain how the equation came to be.

Comment: @gekkostate: In that case, I find your question confusing.  The final question, "Could something be done about this?" sounds to me like you are requesting that the question be closed.

Comment: I also wonder if people are downvoting because they think the question is requesting that the question be closed.  I see no reason to downvote the question otherwise, if it is only out of curiosity and not requesting that it be closed.  (I did not vote one way or the other.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, I downvoted because it looks to me that Gekkostate is requesting that the question be closed. He professes otherwise in the reply to 5pm above, but that seems inconsistent with writing "Could something be done about this?" in the question and explicitly "I think the question should be closed because ..." in his first comment to your answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Please see my edit. There, I have clarified the reason for the question and for the true intent of the question. In response to my comment at Jonas Meyer, I was trying to explain that those were some of the reasons, we generally close questions so why not this one? So my question is leaning more towards the "why" and not "I want **you** to close the question"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that the "you must show some prior work" maxim applies with greater force to homework questions, and even there it rarely leads to even blatantly violating questions being closed.

Conversely, the rule applies *less* (i.e. not at all) to non-homework questions by non-mathematicians. There the asker is not *supposed to* know already how to start doing any work. There seems to be no benefit to anyone from enforcing a rule that prevents such people from asking questions.

The Batman question is clearly in the latter category.

Comment: +1 from one who rarely knows where to start...

Answer (score 2):

While the batman question is not closed, it is after all *protected* and I guess more is not needed. Maybe we feel a bit awkward that the second best voted question is about a joke (though not by the Joker, nor was the question by the Riddler)? But there's no reason for that and the votes speak for themselves (by definition).

To make the queston better related to high end math, remember that the batman logo often gets displayed at night under [moonshine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonshine_theory).